# postgres cannot create extension postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i installed postgres on a new vps and then i installed postgis, but trying to create a postgis extension i always get this error:

```
    create extension postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.so": /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20)
```

i have no idea how to solve it.

i also tried to install openssl and libssl-dev but didn't help

edit:
i am using 18.04.4 LTS ubuntu

i install issuing:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

Comment: Which linux distro are you using? Also, could you add how you've installed postgis?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, after running those commands on 18.04, `sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis"` works fine.

Comment: @jjanes I believe that the package `postgis` does not place the libraries in the directories that postgres 10 looks in, while `postgresql-10-postgis-3` specifically copies the libraries to the postgres 10 directories. At least I remember having this problem many times and being able to solve it using `postgresql-10-postgis-3` (for v10).

Comment: @91DarioDev any luck with the extension?

Comment: @JimJones, well it did work for me in v10.  I'm guessing he has some other packages installed or removed or broken or misconfigured.  For example, why should loading this to PostgreSQL even be touching libmysqlclient.so.20?  But anyway, not using the repository flagged as "unstable" to get the packages might be a good idea for him.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue with Ubuntu 18.04

For missing OpenSSL 1.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 take a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1102966). You might need to download the [.deb file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/amd64/openssl/download) and install it manually.

#### PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.4

In this [article](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/upgrading-postgis-on-centos-7) a similar error is solved by creating a symbolic link to the `rtpostgis` library available in the system, so that you can trick PostGIS 2.4 into thinking that the file exists, e.g. `rtpostgis-2.5.so` to `rtpostgis-2.4.so`:

```
$ ln -s rtpostgis-2.4.so rtpostgis-2.5.so
```

#### PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 3

To install PostGIS 3 (newer version) in a PostgreSQL 10 environment try:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10-postgis-3
```

After that you will have the required libraries to perform  `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`.

Comment: To nowadays, `sudo apt install postgresql-12-postgis-3`

Comment: We have `postgresql-10-postgis-2.4` (this is available on Ubuntu 18.04) installed and are still running into this issue.